# Pretend or reverse encryption

Tags: mount, backup, encryption

I have a network share that contains some files and folders and I want to mount it in a way that everyone who reads it through this mount point sees only encrypted data (data is encrypted on the fly).
Also when someone writes to the mount point the data is decrypted on the fly.
The scenario that I'm interested in is giving an on-line sync application like Dropbox access to the mount point so that it cannot see the real data.
I want to use the Dropbox as a backup mechanism.
The reason for this is that I don't want to maintain duplicate data (normal vs encrypted) in a way that tools like CryptSync require you to do (http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/CryptSync.html)
It feels like wasting space when it should not be necessary.
Is there any ready solution to this problem or maybe you could point me to some tools that I could start reading about (I'm completely new to Linux and filesystem crypting tools).

Comment: I think you might have the meaning of encrypted and decrypted backwards?

Comment: @bc2946088 I think not :P, I want to reverse what typical disk encryption does. I want to encrypt on reads and decrypt on writes to disk so that a program like Dropbox is fooled and never sees real data. How else would you describe it?